# How to overwrite settings set on attrs on styled components once extending a style?

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components

Is there anyway that I can remove the atributes which are inherited by the `styled-component` which has been extended from another one?

I will state a really quite stupid piece of code just to illustrate what I mean:

```
const FormInput = styled.input.attrs({
  type: "text",
})`
  border-color: blue;  
  color: red;
  ${({$size}) => `
  height: ${$size}rem;
  width: ${$size}rem;
  `}
`;

const Label = styled(FormInput)``
```

`type: "text"` is inherited by `Label`. Is there anyway that I could not have it rendered in this case? Let's say that I would render `<Label as="Label" />` in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 5.1 you can pass a [`shouldforwardprop`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#shouldforwardprop) predicate to `.withConfig()`, and filter out properties that you don't want to render:

```
const Label = styled(FormInput).withConfig({
  shouldForwardProp: (prop, defaultValidatorFn) =>
      !['type'].includes(prop)
      && defaultValidatorFn(prop),
})``;
```

To filter out several properties, extract the array to a `const`:

```
const forbiddenProps = ['type', 'placeholder'];

const Label = styled(FormInput).withConfig({
  shouldForwardProp: (prop, defaultValidatorFn) =>
      !forbiddenProps.includes(prop)
      && defaultValidatorFn(prop),
})``;
```

Comment: I see... I have understanding of this API, but I did not figure that this would be a use case. Thanks so much! Now, how would be a nice syntax in case I wanted to filter several props? With your example, which is the same syntax provided by the official docs, would make this quite unreadable.